# expo start in the command line through Exit status 1 Failed at the @ start script

Tags: npm, windows-10, expo, npm-start

Executing the expo start in the command prompt facing the below issue,

> ```
> 0 info it worked if it ends with ok
> 1 verbose cli [
> 1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
> 1 verbose cli   'C:\\Users\\dineshkumars2\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
> 1 verbose cli   'start'
> 1 verbose cli ]
> 2 info using npm@6.14.8
> 3 info using node@v12.14.0
> 4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
> 5 info lifecycle @~prestart: @
> 6 info lifecycle @~start: @
> 7 verbose lifecycle @~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
> 8 verbose lifecycle @~start: PATH: C:\Users\dineshkumars2\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;C:\Panasonic_data\mymobileapp\panasonic.maintenance.tablet\node_modules\.bin;C:\Python39\Scripts\;C:\Python39\;C:\Program Files (x86)\RSA SecurID Token Common;C:\Program Files\RSA SecurID Token Common;C:\Program Files\Microsoft MPI\Bin\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Windows\CCM;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\130\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\170\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\;C:\Program Files\PuTTY\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\150\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\150\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin;C:\Program Files\Genymobile\Genymotion\tools;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files\RSA SecurID Token Common\;C:\Users\dineshkumars2\AppData\Roaming\npm
> 9 verbose lifecycle @~start: CWD: C:\Panasonic_data\mymobileapp\panasonic.maintenance.tablet
> 10 silly lifecycle @~start: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'expo start' ]
> 11 silly lifecycle @~start: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
> 12 info lifecycle @~start: Failed to exec start script
> 13 verbose stack Error: @ start: `expo start`
> 13 verbose stack Exit status 1
> 13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Users\dineshkumars2\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:332:16)
> 13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:210:5)
> 13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\dineshkumars2\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
> 13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:210:5)
> 13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
> 13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:283:5)
> 14 verbose pkgid @
> 15 verbose cwd C:\Panasonic_data\mymobileapp\panasonic.maintenance.tablet
> 16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.17134
> 17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\dineshkumars2\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
> 18 verbose node v12.14.0
> 19 verbose npm  v6.14.8
> 20 error code ELIFECYCLE
> 21 error errno 1
> 22 error @ start: `expo start`
> 22 error Exit status 1
> 23 error Failed at the @ start script.
> 23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reinstalled expo and node working me,

1. npm -g uninstall expo-cli --save.
2. Second go to \Users<yourUser>\ and then remove .expo folder
3. Open the Windows Control Panel.
   Choose the Programs and Features option.
   Click the “Uninstall a program”
   Select Node. js, and click the Uninstall link.
4. reinstalled the node 14 version from the link https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v14.x/.
5. again installed the expo, npm install -g expo-cli
6. expo start

working now.